# Serverless Framework Secrets Error - An error occurred while calling one AWS dependency service

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am trying to access secret managers using Serverless secrets framework this way:

- Approach1 (Old)

  supersecret: ${ssm(us-east-1, raw):/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret-name~true}
- Approach2 (New)

  variablesResolutionMode: 20210326 in serverless.yaml

  supersecret: ${ssm(us-east-1, raw):/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret-name}

Approach1 works fine, but I get the below error with Approach2 on serverless deploy-

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.lambdas.test.custom.supersecret": An error occurred while calling one AWS dependency service.
```

Serverless version -
Framework Core: 2.69.1 (local)
Plugin: 5.5.1
SDK: 4.3.0
Components: 3.18.1

The secrets are not replicated and only exist in us-east-1. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any further error logs that mention what AWS service failed? Did you try to run serverless in verbose mode to get more output?

Comment: i'm having the same issue, can't figure out if there's a wildcard permission/policy i can apply somewhere just to get it to work; but I'm starting to think i shouldn't put secrets in "static context" (like lambda environment variables) anyway, and instead call them from *within* the lambda

Answer (score 8):

Yesterday, I had the same error. Well, the error comes from serverless's version I was using. In my local environment, I had the version 2.3 and it works fine with the flag `~true` after my `secret_name` ID, but in my CD I had version 3.*, and that was generating the error. After reading the docs, I searched:

***Note: The method described below works by default in Serverless v3, but it requires the `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326` option in v2.***

So, if you're using v3 use:

```
ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/my_secret_name
```

or

```
ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/my_secret_name~true
```

instead